# Python get file from an app on-the-fly (without saving it in file system)

Tags: python, output, python-docx, on-the-fly

I want to let user submit a MS Word file to my app, process it with python-docx library and return it back. Since a file size might be big, I do not want to save it into the file system after processing but rather return it for download.

**Get file from stream - this works**

```
import docx
from docx.document import Document 
from StringIO import StringIO

source_stream = StringIO(request.vars['file'].value)
document = docx.Document(source_stream)
source_stream.close()
process_doc(document)
```

**Return it as a stream - this does not work**

The app *makes indeed user to download file*, but *MS Word can't open file, saying *"because some part is missing or invalid"*.

```
def download(document, filename):
    import contenttype as c
    import cStringIO
    out_stream = cStringIO.StringIO()
    document.save(out_stream)  

    response.headers['Content-Type'] = c.contenttype(filename)
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
            "attachment; filename=%s" %  filename
    return out_stream.getvalue()
```

I've found [Upload a StringIO object with send_file()](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/32/) but this persist to the flask framework. I rather use *web2py framework*.

### Update 1

Some said about moving file pointer to the start of document data before sending it in output stream. But how to do it?

### Update 2

As @scanny has suggested, I've created an empty file,

```
document = docx.Document()
```

and made it to download from file object using `BytesIO` module:

```
document = docx.Document() 
from io import BytesIO
out_stream = BytesIO()
document.save(out_stream)
filename = 'temporal_file.docx'
filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads',filename )
try:
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(out_stream.getvalue())
    response.flash ='Success to open file for writing'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    #response['X-Sendfile'] = filepath
    #response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(filepath).st_size
    return  out_stream.getvalue()
```

As seen in the code, I also write that empty file into the file-system. And I could **easily manually download it and open it in MS word**:
[image]

So, still the question is open **why the downloaded MS Word file (thru the output stream) is damaged and cannot be opened by MS Word**?

### Update 3

I've eliminated `python-docx` from the process of file output into an out stream. And the result was the same: after the file download process one can't open it in MS Word. Code:

```
# we load without python-docx library
from io import BytesIO
try:
    filename = 'empty_file.docx'
    filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads',filename )
    # read a file from file system (disk)
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f: 
        out_stream = BytesIO(f.read())
    response.flash ='Success to open file for reading'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'
    return out_stream.getvalue()
except Exception as e:
    response.flash ='Error open file for reading or download it - ' + filename
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by saving to the file-like object and then copying that file-like object to a file (locally, without downloading it). That should bisect the range of where the problem is happening. By the way, I'd use BytesIO instead of StringIO. It might not make a difference in 2.7, but it could, and StringIO won't work in Python 3 in any case:

```
from io import BytesIO

# ... code that processes `document`
out_stream = BytesIO()
document.save(out_stream)
with open('test.docx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(out_stream.getvalue())
```

If that doesn't work (`test.docx` won't open), you've narrowed the problem to "before" the `document.save()` call.

If it *does* work, you can try the download again and see, but pay particular attention to the type expected as the `return` value from your download method. What you'd be getting here is a sequence of bytes. If it's expecting a file-like object or perhaps a path, that could be the problem too.

Moving the file pointer to the start (using out_stream.seek(0)) would only be relevant if you were returning a file-like object, like `return out_stream` instead of `return outstream.getvalue()`. The latter returns `bytes`, which of course don't have a file pointer. BytesIO (or StringIO).getvalue() does not require setting the file cursor; it always returns the full contents of the object.

Also, instead of relying on `contenttype` to get it right, I'd spell out the content-type header as: `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`. If contenttype misidentified the file as a .doc format (pre-Word 2007) file as opposed to a .docx format (Word 2007 and later) file, that could also cause a problem.

Comment: *I'd use BytesIO instead of StringIO* - this part works.

Comment: I've followed your instruction as to the content-type header - `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` and still after I download file I can't open it. - http://joxi.ru/52aQW1dC4Boy02

Comment: @IgorSavinkin I can't help you without further information. I suggest you start making the problem simpler by removing variables until you find the one that breaks it. For example, you could create an empty document with `Document()` and try downloading that and see if you can open it. That would eliminate the source-stream aspect. If it was still broken, you could try saving the file to disk and see if that one was openable. You could also try downloading a file right from disk and make sure that worked.

Comment: I've followed your advise, see Update 2.

Comment: Okay, so this is very useful test, I think it points to the problem being with your use of the Flask download mechanism rather than `python-docx`. You could further confirm that by removing `python-docx` from the mix altogether, with something like: `with open('file.docx', 'wb') as f: out_stream = BytesIO(f.read())` and confirming the download is still a problem.

Comment: thanks. But I use `web2py` framework rather than `Flask`.